# ¿Cómo reiniciar el timer de RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Quiero hacer un contador de tiempo. Y que al presionar un botón se reinicie. Para ello estoy usando Angular 7 y el operador `timer` de RxJS.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  tiempo = 0;

  constructor() {
    timer(0, 1000).subscribe(t => this.tiempo = t);
  }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo reiniciar el operador `timer`?

Answer (score 2):

Puede hacer algo como esto:

```
  inscribir: any;

  onComenzar() {
    const source = timer(0, 1000);
    this.inscribir = source.subscribe(val => this.tiempo = val);
  }

  onDetener() {
    this.inscribir.unsubscribe();
  }

En la vista podrías tener algo así para los eventos de Comenzar y Detener el Timer:

  <h2> tiempo: {{ tiempo }}</h2>
  <button (click)="onComenzar()">Comenzar Timer</button>
  <button (click)="onDetener()">Detener Timer</button>
```

Comment: Sí, de hecho fue la manera en que lo hice, aunque para reiniciarlo, además del `.unsubscribe`, me volví a subscribir para que el timer empezará de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con `Subject` y `switchMap`

```
private reiniciar$: Subject<void>;
tiempo = 0;

constructor() {
    this.reiniciar$ = new Subject<void>();
    this.reiniciar$
        .asObservable()
        .pipe(
            startWith(null),
            switchMap(() => timer(0, 1000))
        )
        .subscribe(t => this.tiempo = t);
}

reiniciar() {
    this.reiniciar$.next();
}
```